# After change from HTTP to HTTPs, landing page works, rest not

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, osclass

I'm using OsClass for my website. When I've activated ssl certificate, my webside was down. I've updated my .htacess with code which I've got from my hosting

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

so finally I can see my web, landing page, oc-admin... but rest of the page is down

```
Not Found

The requested URL /item/new was not found on this server.
```

Hope it is just something simple. Can you please help me with that ?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the rewrite condition? Does it work without it?

Comment: not sure what it is. Please try to be more specific

Comment: ok, its working now, I had to fix also permalinks with htaccess